# Extending nicEdit to include line-height

Tags: javascript, nicedit

Does anyone know how to extend nicEdit to include a line-height option? It looks easily extendible and I can't imagine it would be that hard to add another drop down to the menu bar but my Javascript skills just aren't up to it!

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'll have have a go at this myself!